# vagrant provision launches apps without ui on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, vagrant

I am trying to launch an application that needs ui on a windows box as part of "vagrant provision". I can see that the app is launched as the vagrant user in task manager but I see no ui on the screen.

For example if I use something as simple as:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  notepad
SHELL
```

I need the ui - why does it not show ? Now there might be a better way to launch the app, still I am curious whats going on ?

Running the same directly on the machine in powershell works fine.

Comment: Look at how the user is running, for example it can be `SYSTEM` user. Then, to access it graphical tool should also start from under the same user.

Comment: Vagrant runs any provisioning under the vagrant user by default and because of double hop and UAC issues it already runs all provisioners through a scheduled task. The reason this isn't working is because the provisioner runs under a different login session - even if it's the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to use `schtasks` to trigger the command, something like this:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  # Create a task that will never run automatically
  schtasks /create /tn "notepad" /tr "notepad.exe" /sc monthly /st 07:00 /sd 01/01/1980 /f
  # Run it now
  schtasks /run /tn notepad
SHELL
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the [`powershell_elevated_interactive`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#powershell_elevated_interactive) option (which apparently creates and runs a scheduled task under the covers).